# Issue with running two virtual machines using virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, cpu

I’ve been trying to run two virtual machines (A linux VM and A Windows VM) using virtual box however whatever second machine I try to run it won’t run. It freezes. I understand that it depends on my host machine’s processor strength and memory space but I can’t really purchase a new computer so isn’t there any way to increase my processor speed and memory space? Like a device I could buy a hard disk for example.
My host machine:
iMac
2.66 Ghz Intel corei5
Memory 4 GB

My Linux& Windows VMs:
2 CPUs
Base memory 2389 MB

All I want is to run two VMs simultaneously is it possible.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You definitely need more RAM, there is no way around that. In addition to that it seems like you're giving the VMs more memory than physically availible.

Comment: Which operating system on the host and is it 32-bit or 64-bit? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My host machine: iMac 2.66 Ghz Intel corei5 Memory 4 GB
>
> My Linux& Windows VMs: 2 CPUs Base memory 2389 MB

Your answer is in your two lines.

You cannot apply all the memory of the host to two machines and expect it to run and it is not running.

You either need to add more memory to your host (8GB minimum) or get a host with more capacity.

A virtual machine should not use more than 1/2 of the overall Host Resource (CPU and Memory).

You can try using less memory per machine, but a 4 GB host does not allow much room and the machines will likely drag for lack of memory

Comment: Hey @John. I bought RAM and I’ll increase it to 12GB. Hope the performance becomes better than expected. Thank you